# Chart.js radar with different scales

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to create a radar chart with Chart.js, similar to the ones shown on this site: http://whereaboutslondon.org/#/map

Here is an example:
[image]

The scale (distance from center to edge) has been computed, as a value between 0 and 100. This is working fine, but I'd like to also display the figure, as shown in the picture (i.e. 811K).

Is there a way to provide a label on a radar image of this type?

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Not really, we just moved to normalised data (out of 100%) and eventually scrapped the chart all together, so I hadn't looked further than that.