# Independent axes in Chart.js radar chart

Tags: javascript, plot, charts

I'm trying to make a radar chart in Chart.js not unlike [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712103/chart-js-radar-with-different-scales). However, I would like to actually really plot independent scales for each axis and not rescale as the author of the linked question does.

I would e.g. have

- number of apples (0-1e5)
- number of boxes (0-1e3)
- number of trucks to transport apples (0-10)
- quality rating of apples (0-5)
- number of types of apples (0-8)

I want to be able to plot the as I have them and have the given maximum be the axis maximum for that one axes. So, I would end up with something like this:

[image]

(Don't mind that this image was taken from a [critique of radar charts which argues against their use](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2011/09/23/a-critique-of-radar-charts.html).)

Can this be done in Chart.js?

I've tried a configuration like this:

```
{
  scale: [
    {ticks: {min: 0, max: 10000}},
    {ticks: {min: 0, max: 1000}},
    {ticks: {min: 0, max: 10}},
    {ticks: {min: 0, max: 5}},
    {ticks: {min: 0, max: 8}}
  ]
}
```

However, that list doesn't seem to be accepted and the whole configuration is ignored. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: I guess it can't